# CSS To Make Vertical Scrolling Region Under Fixed Header?

Tags: css

**Goal:**
Emulate the fixed header and scrollable content of *this StackOverflow page:*

- Footer under the content scrolls up as the content scrolls up.
- When paging-down (via keyboard), nothing gets clipped by the header. Ie, content *cannot go behind the header.*
- Anchors do not go behind the header.
- No double-scrollbars.
- If i increase height of header (eg on hover), the page content does not get pushed down further (ie, the taller header just covers more of the content).
- `#header`, `#content`, and `#footer` divs are siblings

`<div id="header">This is the header.</div>`

`<div id='content'>This is the content.</div>`

`<div id='footer'>This is the footer.</div>`

Url of site to be applied: https://gunretort.xyz/index.php/Portal:Tag?Tag=CommonGround

**Body Padding Fails:**
A common recommendation is `body{padding-top:...}`, to push #content down. But it doesn't really push content down-- content still scrolls behind the header, so as you page down, the top of the content gets clipped by the header. Anchors land behind the header, where they can't be seen.

Example of content behind header:

[image]

Click 'Go to anchor' in this example to see the problem. 
https://codepen.io/johnyradio/pen/pKxBwQ

**StackOverflow:**
StackOverflow does it right. The footer scrolls up with content, as desired. #content and #footer are sibs. I'm seeing the following in the CSS for this page, but i don't know if this is the magic.

```
#content {
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: calc(100% - 164px);
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    display: block;
}

#content:before, #content:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

body *, body *:before, body *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

#content:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

**Flex:**
I also see a lot of Flex in the .css files of this SO page. Flex is used in answers below. Problem with those answers-- they break the `#footer`.

**Grid:**
Grid seems like it *should* be the way. But i'm concerned about browser-compatibility. Also, so far, i haven't found a grid solution.

**Overflow:**
This approach uses fixed position to place the #content below the header, without overlap. Making it a fixed-size box with `overflow:auto` gives the #content div it's own scrollbar. We could fix the #footer position below #content, but drawback is the footer would not scroll up-- it would have to occupy permanent real-estate at the bottom of the viewport.

https://codepen.io/johnyradio/pen/aKReor

**+Padding -Margin:**
Some solutions involve padding and margins. That doesn't work consistently for span-anchors, a-links, coming in from same page or a different page. Using `:target` when target-id's aren't known doesn't work in all cases. Also, it doesn't address correct page-down. Also, it just seems more efficient to apply style to the major divs, instead of every single link-target. Any solution requiring knowledge of id or class name won't work, because we won't have that knowledge-- besides, a robust CSS solution covering all current and future cases should not require such knowledge.

```
a[name] {
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

**Frame:**
I'm thinking a frame might be an option, but there's the problem that i cannot change the HTML.

**Not a duplicate:** This question is not a dupe of other threads here. Solutions i've seen on SO don't handle unknown link-targets, page correctly, and scroll the footer (like this page). Eg,

[Body top gap; should I use margin or padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984776/body-top-gap-should-i-use-margin-or-padding)

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow-x: auto` for the content you want to scroll.

In this case the `<main />` block gets its own scrollbar. The content will not go behind the header element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  opacity: .3;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
}

main {
  overflow-x: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Header is semi-opaque</header>
  <main>
    <p><a href='#myAnchor'>Go to anchor</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
    <p><a href='#myAnchor'>Go to anchor</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et earebum.
    <p><span style='color:yellow' id=myAnchor>ANCHOR</span>  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
    <p> rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: i applied your code here. Didn't work for me. Content scrolls behind the header, and the anchor lands behind the header. Please see note about double-scrollbars. Also, your example does not include the anchor-span. https://codepen.io/johnyradio/pen/pKxBwQ

Comment: Then you are using different css. There's no way the content can end up behind the header with this code.

Comment: Ok, i tried your code again (without mixing with code). https://codepen.io/johnyradio/pen/VdEOer Works, but the double-scrollbar is a problem. Plz see note in question about double-scrollbars.

Comment: You forgot to add `margin: 0;` to body. You get the double scrollbar because the default margin is added to `100vh`. With no margin on body, `100vh` should be the exact height of the window, and there's no extra scrollbar for the document element itself.

Comment: Ok, thx, margin:0 works! However, i added another twist re hover on header Sorry! Plz see updated question. Your fix doesn't handle the hover as desired.

Comment: There's no logical way to have both "header should not cover content" _and_ "header should cover more content when it expands" at the same time.

Comment: @KyleLin's solution seems to work as desired, regarding header height (tho' has another issue, mentioned in comments). Seems his content element doesn't care what the header element is doing.

Comment: I think there might be a simpler way to get what you want. But since it's quite different from this solution, I'll just post it as a different answer.

Answer (score 2):

Give your content container a fixed `position`, and set its `top` and `height` accordingly. Finally, make it scrollable with `overflow: auto`.

In short, just replace your `#content` style with this:

```
#content{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

EDIT:

[Here's](https://codepen.io/link26/pen/xzyNwg)  a link to a fork of your pen with the working solution.

Comment: Your code is breaking my site. *Site without your code:* https://image.ibb.co/hFcZzo/Screenshot_366.png  *Site with your code:* https://image.ibb.co/kTXpX8/Screenshot_365.png *Url added to question.*

Comment: i tried changing content width to 100%. That fixed the width problem, but footers (divs under the content) still get lost.

Comment: your answer above doesn't include the full code that's in your codepen. Your codepen also includes CSS for `body`. It gives double-scrollbars. Interestingly, if i use just your `content` css, without using your `body` CSS, *i still get desired behavior*, but WITHOUT double scroll-bars! Only issue is, the footer gets lost (with or without the `body` css).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a trick to make the anchor seem bigger so that clicking the link will not cover the actual anchor text. Since you have negative margin, the anchor element will not take up more space. But it will have a scroll position that is 50px taller.

```
:target {
  padding-top: 50px; 
  margin-top: -50px
}
```

This uses the [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo-class.

> The `:target` CSS pseudo-class represents a unique element (the target
>   element) with an id matching the URL's fragment.

Example: https://codepen.io/haakenlid/pen/oyarva

Comment: thx, the problem with that fix is there are other anchors on the page, not created by me, and in the future there may be more anchors not created by me. I won't know their ID's.

Comment: You can use the `:target` pseudo-class. See updated example

Comment: Great! That may fix the anchor issue. But i think that won't fix the problem of text going behind the header when paging down (see revision in question).

Comment: I think you should post a new question about that instead of changing this one.

Comment: if i posted a new question, it would be the same question. It's all related to the scroll-region of the content.

Comment: In any case I can't help you. I don't have any idea what "paging down in the content" is supposed to mean, but I suspect this is browser-specific behavior that's not related to css.

Comment: "paging" means when you press the "Page Down" key on your keyboard.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution, thx for sharing. But, it's not working on gunretort.xyz. Not sure why.